# How do I create a very long delay with Redstone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

The only things I've found so far are a cart method (which ceased working in 1.6), a dispenser method (utilizing the decay on dropped items, but this requires occasional feeding), and a binary counter (which won't work for a single input but rather a fluctuating one).

I want to have a circuit that when I apply an input signal, the output signal doesn't change for 2 to 5 *minutes.*  When the input turns off, I again want a 2 to 5 minute delay.

I could accomplish this with (roughly) 240 to 600 redstone repeaters, but this is far in excess of being useful.

The only method I can think of, but would require a XOR gate (on the button-input and final output) to start and stop a clock attached to a binary counter.  While I can make room for a device of this size, I was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: What do you want to attach it to? What other mechanisms/blocks are involved? What's your goal for the circuit?

Comment: I can give you a tip: items disappears at 5 minutes in the ground

Comment: Would you mind actually providing a circuit that uses this principle?

Comment: If you're willing to use a Bukkit plugin, several Craftbook IC's can help you here: Clock, Clock Divider, Rising Edge T flip Flop, links respectively: http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/CraftBook/MC1421, http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/CraftBook/MC1420, http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/CraftBook/MC1017.

Comment: 1) This question is three years old.  2) Its been answered sufficiently.  3) This question is THREE YEARS OLD

Comment: This thread has turned into a beautiful history of clocks in minecraft <3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Minecraftaddict's "Extreme Delay Redstone Timer" is the longest delay circuit I know of. (But I can see from the comments that you've already found it). However, directly using this circuit won't work with a light sensor output, since the output of a light sensor would be 10 minutes on and 10 minutes off.

The solution to this is to connect the output of your light sensor to a falling-edge and rising-edge monostable circuit that are OR'd together.

[image: Rising-edge on the left, falling-edge on the right.]

This is an image of a rising-edge trigger on the left, and a falling-edge trigger on the right. You would connect the A inputs together – to the output of your light trigger. When the A input is turned on, the Q output of the left circuit pulses. When the A output turns off, the Q output of the right circuit pulses. Because of this, you can connect the two Q output wires together (ORing them) to have an output that sends a signal whenever the light-sensor changes.

However, these circuits are designed to make a *very* short pulse. Because Minecraftaddict's delay circuit comes with a built-in pulse shortener, you will want to send a slightly longer signal to it. To do this, just add more repeaters to the edge triggers (add an extra repeater to when the current repeaters are). Leave the repeaters that should be on the first setting like that, but change the repeaters that should be on the second setting (according to the image) to the fourth setting.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the video I had been looking for, and then found. :)

Answer (score 14):

The longest I can think out of top of my head?

[image]

Fill the dropper with as many items as many days you want the signal to take. Near each noon the dropper will discard one item, for a max of 576 in-game days. If that's not enough, you can restock the dropper with a chain of hoppers and a double chests, and only when all the items are exhausted the signal will be produced.

If you want this retriggerable, with limit of 320 days you can "discard" the items into a hopper blocked with a piece of redstone that will be deactivated once the time is past, and feed all the items back in.

If you want something faster, clock that dropper with a pair of repeaters or any of hundreds minor clocks. With an adjustable clock and a specific number of items you will easily fit within that 3-5 minutes range.

Comment: The daylight sensor doesn't have to be that far from the dropper. Your device can be a bit more compact while retaining the same delay.

Comment: Brilliant!  This is amazingly compact!

Answer (score 11):

Use several clocks and an `AND` gate

A clock that takes 7 ticks and one that takes 8 ticks will output every 56 ticks, using only 5 repeaters instead of 15. Using this method you can use 6 repeaters to get a 42s (420 tick) delay.

You simply have a clock that takes 3 ticks (1), a clock that takes 4 ticks (+1=2), A clock that takes 5 (+2=4), and a clock that takes 7 (+2=6 repeaters).

3 x 4 x 5 x 7 = 420.

Comment: This is a great solution!

Answer (score 10):

Scott Chamberlain's answer is pretty good but if you don't like the complexity of pistons, here is a compact T flip flop without them:

[image: T flip flop, compact, no pistons]!

Here is a ~2 minute long clock:

[image: chained T-flip flops and a clock]

Note that each extra T flip flop will halve the clock speed. Also note that a small change in the initial clock's repeaters will greatly affect the result.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend using a slow [automatic clock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_circuits#Clock_generators) (See B') tied in to a chain of [T flip flops](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_circuits#T_Flip-Flop), (if you have access to sticky pistons you can make them extremely compact, see the Z layouts).

[image]

In the above diagram A would take 2x long to cycle, B would take 4x long, c would take 8x long, D would take 16x long.

As you see it gets very long very fast, I doubt you would need more than 4 or 5 T flip flops to get a 2-5 min delay.

Comment: The TFF idea won't work, as I have a slow input signal (it's the output from a light sensor, so it toggles on every sunrise and off every sunset) and wanted to tie that to a door so the door would stay open for ~5 minutes.  A TFF would require a clock-input, and the clock would have to be turned on and off based on the initial input signal.

I found a solution though, digging through this one guy's youtube videos.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsC2xoQi38I Extremely compact design that can be delayed exponentially through a linear increase in circuit size.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand the question. Glad you got help, you should post the details of your solution as an answer. There is nothing wrong with answering your own question on this site if you figured it out yourself.

Comment: I'd have posted my own solution, except I can't for about 5 more hours. :P

Guy below, however, did have what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

for 5 minutes exactly you could have a dispenser drop an item onto a pressure plate, and the item would disappear after 5 minutes

I also have a video of what I use when I need long pulses on my youtube channel

You could modify this to use a system to activate the circuit several times sequentially to save space. I may do a video on that again some time.

Comment: @Fambida I second the statement.

Answer (score 4):

I've recently worked out this circuit:
[image]

On the right is one of [Etho](http://www.youtube.com/user/EthosLab)'s [Hopper timer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYwzd62cLSw), which can be extend to about three and a half minutes, with precise adjustment by adjusting the number of items in it.  On the left is another hopper timer, just like it.  The timer on the left is not being used as a timer, but rather, a counter, counting the number of times the timer on the right has cycled.  The redstone on the hoppers on the left disable the counter except when the timer on the right resets, and then allows it to run just long enough to allow one item to shift around.

When all of the items have shifted in the counter from one hopper to the other, it switches the output on the far left 'on', and all the items have to shift back to the first.  After a full round trip, the clock and the output turns 'off'

Since the counter has a capacity of 5 stacks of up to 64 items, and the input clock has a maximum delay of 3.7 minutes; this clock can be adjusted to have a cycle time as long as **40 HOURS!**.  If that's not long enough, add another counter to the output of the first; which will top out at a delay of almost 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

Minecart tracks can easily be extended to provide a very long delay, taking up (relatively) little space. The space they take up can easily be put anywhere you want too, which will avoid clogging up your circuit.

Wire up the output of this circuit to a flip flop, and have your input connected to a [cart dispenser](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/31032-mine-cart-dispenser/). When you hit toggle, a cart is released. 5 minutes later it will arrive and switch the flip flop. You can then return the carts to the dispenser.

[image: Minecart delay]

*Add more tracks as required*

I'd recommend tight spirals of track to extend the time, which ensures they won't stray into a chunk that might get unloaded.

Comment: You'd be surprised how much track you need for a 5 minute long loop!  We've got a whole metro system that takes about 3 minutes for a complete loop and took several hundred track to build.

(It's also going to get a track-switching upgrade here soon, as soon as I can work out the schematic with sticky pistons and assuming it's better than what we have now)

Comment: Couldn't you wire this to a counter? After 10 loops the counter fires, say?

Comment: Binary counter, yeah.  Would work.

Comment: A mixture of methods is likely to be good. Make a binary counter out of minecarts!

Comment: Impractical solution

Answer (score 0):

A 2-hopper clock.  Immediately beside it a redstone t-flip flop, that uses the redstone to toggle the active hopper.  a single falling-edge pulse emitter using a comparator-repeater feed off of one side of the hopper clock.  that emitter feeds back around to the input of the flip flop.  a single feed from your daylight sensor between the pulse emitter and the flip flop.  This is how it works.  One side is fed with as many items as it takes to count out half (HALF) of the time you need.  The clock is normally at rest.  An 'on' signal from your detector flips the t-flipflop, activating the hopper clock.  items xfer from one side to the other.  once full, a signal from the comparator-repeater off your hopper clock activates the falling-edge pulse emitter, toggling the tflipflop, and thus your clock.  the other hopper empties back.  The clock works for one full cycle, then halts, waiting for another input from your detector and is FULLY customizable on the timeframe.  I use this setup to make a bridge across lava that only stays up so long after a button press.