# How can I make a redstone button with an X second delay?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am making a grinder that kills you with lava, water, TNT and sends you into the void.
I am having some trouble with the lava. Since lava flows really slow, I need a button that has a delay from 5 to 7 seconds. I've tried circuits with lots of repeaters. How can I create a button which has a 5 to 7 second delay?

---

The machine is out! [4-way killing machine](http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/4-way-killing-machine/)

Comment: I'm more interested in the first sentence rather than the button.

Comment: Do you want a button that *waits* 5 to 7 seconds before sending a signal, or do you want a button that *maintains a signal* for 5 to 7 seconds? Those are very different.

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be a signal that lasts 5-7 seconds, to lift a block up and leave it there for enough time for the lava to pass.

Comment: @RussellWhitchurch Then they've asked an incomplete question and made the XY Problem mistake, where they ask for what they *think* is the answer instead of telling us what problem they're trying to solve. What they actually want is a bucket of lava in a dispenser. I've voting to close until the question is fixed.

Comment: @thomson159 Please describe your problem in detail and tell us exactly what you want the button to do and why. Could you describe how the lava activates? I don't want to seem insulting, but what are you *really* trying to do? We need to make sure there isn't an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which I found out about 5 minutes ago reading SevenSidedDie's comment. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a very long delay with Redstone?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28558/how-do-i-create-a-very-long-delay-with-redstone)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working concept of what you're probably looking for:

[image: Working concept]

The trick is to split the output with varying delays, then each of them take their turn keeping the gate lifted up. The more rows of repeaters you have (with increasing length), the longer the button's signal.

Answer (score 3):

Another concept to use is a little bit more complicated to set up, but is more efficient and space effective in the long run.

1. Connect your button to an RS NOR latch to trigger it ON when you press the button.
2. Create a long line of repeaters that matches the amount of time you want the button to stay "pressed".
3. Connect your line of repeaters to turn your RS NOR latch OFF.

The result is a button the turns the output on, then after X seconds your repeaters will turn it back off.

If you don't know, an RS NOR latch is a bit that "remembers" it's state. Build it by making a redstone clock with 2 nodes.

```
"-" = Red stone
"O" = Solid block
"*" = Torch on block

--O
*X*
O--
```

Comment: You're missing a label for `X`.

Comment: i've changed the machine: the button became a lever and I just setteled a sticky piston witha block atatched to it above it and I made a reset button so that the piston goes down and the lever gets nocked of. I've based it on an idea from sethbling, he made a machine that puts its self out, that uses a lever that activates a piston that via a redstone circuit puts the lever out. that machine is used in his map 'pile of bodies'. so I used that as an idea for my machine. and I changed the machine a little bit so the tntis changed to suffication.