# How to make a block swapper fire twice?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

How do I make my block swapper fire once (changing the block) then after a certain amount of timer change back to the original blocks.
My block swapper can be seen here:[image]

Comment: This is not something that is exclusive to block swappers, you can just make a direct line to some circuit and a longer line with lots of repeaters that leads to the same circuit, no matter what the circuit is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a very long delay with Redstone?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28558/how-do-i-create-a-very-long-delay-with-redstone)

Comment: @FabianRöling: Generating exactly two pulses from a single input pulse is not something covered by the question you have linked. That one is about pulse extenders of quite extreme length, this asks about a pulse multiplicator (specifically, doubler) of several seconds length. It's really wrong of you to mark every question asking for any sort of delay, from half a second to 10 minutes, as duplicate of the question with answers that go into years of delay.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the answers through completely. I thought of a different question. I'm pretty sure there's a question somewhere with answers like long repeater chains, shooting an item into a cobweb, etc., not such extreme stuff. And making two pulses is really extremely basic, as I said, just a direct connection and a delayed connection.

Answer (score 0):

Pulse extender -> dual edge detector.

The easiest would be probably a fader pulse extender, with its output (stabilized by a repeater) observed by an observer (acting as dual edge detector.)

[image: pulse doubler]

If you need the delay a little longer, add extra comparators in series with the two.